# Given group G and subgroup H, how can I show that no g in G and outside H exists such that gH is equivalent to H?

Tags: group-theory

Given group G and subgroup H, how can I show that no element g in G and outside H exists such that gH is equivalent to H?
g is not in H and H is a group, so g can't be the identity. Can I prove only the identity times H would be equivalent to H? I'm not sure that's even true, so perhaps that's not the best approach. Maybe instead I could show that any element in G that multiplies H and yields H must be in H. How could I show that, or how else can I prove gH is not equivalent to H for g in G but not H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of subgroup, if $g \in H$, then $gH=H$.

However, if $g \notin H$, then noting that $1 \in H$ and $gH \ni g \cdot 1 = g \notin H$ shows that $gH \ne H$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: sufficient to prove that gH=H iff g€H, and it can be proved trivially.